# How to retrieve XML/RDF data from a link URL using in Java?

Tags: java, xml, http

I have been trying to retrieve XML data from a URL and write to file on disk `http://dbpedia.org/data/Berlin.rdf` using the following code snippet.

```
URL urlObj = new URL("http://dbpedia.org/data/Berlin.rdf");
java.net.HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
InputStream reader = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
BufferedReader breader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(reader));
String line;        
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new eWriter("resource.xml"));

while ((line = breader.readLine()) != null) {   
    // writes the line to the output file
    writer.write(line);

    System.out.println(line);
    }
writer.close();
connection.disconnect();
```

But I get this error:  Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 502 for URL: http://dbpedia.org/data/Berlin.rdf
What is wrong ? How to fix this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I  was able to run without an error.

Answer (score 2):

A [502 HTTP Error](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) is a Server Error.

If you go to the site (http://dbpedia.org/data/Berlin.rdf), you will see that dbpedia is currently undergoing maintenance. Go back in a couple of hours and try again and your code should work fine.

[image]

**Update:** It's working fine now.